# cannot host angular website to Github Pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am new to angular and trying to host website to github, I have created a repo and also a branch on it. Executed following commands:

```sh
ng build --base-href "https://username.github.io/reponame/"
npm i angular-cli-ghpages --save-dev
ngh --dir=dist/[projectname]
```

but at the last step I am receiving this error:

> *index.html could not be copied to 404.html. This does not look like an angular-cli project?!
> (Hint: are you sure that you have setup the directory correctly?)
> Diagnostic info: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/[foldername]/Published/[reponame]/dist/[projectname]/index.html'
>  Uploading via git, please wait...
> ❌ An error occurred when trying to deploy:
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/foldername/Published/reponame/dist/projectname'*

I tried changing the `--base-href` many times. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Great that you are trying to setup an Angular app on Github Pages. Now the idea for that to work is you can only host static Angular website. As you know, while setting up the pages under github settings, we can define the default branch name from where the code needs to be pulled.

Next, assuming that you have created the build for your app and it resides under

`<repo>/dist/<project>/`

Now you need to understand that, the default file for any web app is index.html. So keep the build folder directly under your pages defined branch and you'll be good to go.

Let me know if you need further help.

Happy Coding :)